# Overlay an opacified image with an icon

Tags: html, css

Basically what I'm trying to do is overlay an image with an icon (`display: none` at first), then add a hover effect to show up the icon and opacify the image. It doesn't work.

So is there any way to overlay an icon on top of an opacified image?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/w084goLp/1/

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
img {
  // opacity: 0.7; // Cannot overlay opacified image?

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="icon">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="https://cdn.lynda.com/courses/457872-635961558500122446_270x480_thumb.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have to move the icon into the `.thumbnail` wrapper, to apply an effect on hover over `.thumbnail`. Then you just can set `display: block;` on hover and your icon appears.

You also need to give `.icon` a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) greater than zero because of your [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) or you put it after the thumbnail image in your markup. Plus you can easily position your `.icon` in the center of `.thumbnail` just because it is a child of it.

```css
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.icon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.thumbnail:hover img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.thumbnail:hover .icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="thumbnail">
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <img src="https://cdn.lynda.com/courses/457872-635961558500122446_270x480_thumb.jpg">
</div>
```

Another possibility (if you don't have the option to put your `.icon` inside your `.thumbnail`), you can place `.icon` after `.thumbnail` and use the adjacent sibling selector `+`. A disadvantage would be, that you can't use position to align your `.icon` relative to `.thumbnail`.

```css
.icon {
  display: none;
  font-size: 10em;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.thumbnail:hover img {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.thumbnail:hover + .icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="https://cdn.lynda.com/courses/457872-635961558500122446_270x480_thumb.jpg">
</div>
<div class="icon">
  <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate!!